# Find and fill in a field in a browser window

Tags: r, url, browser

I need to open a URL from R, then find and fill in a specific field in it with some values calculated in R. Is there any way of doing that?

P.S. I do not need to retrieve anything back from the browser, I just need to fill one field and leave the browser window open.

P.P.S. I have heard about `RSelenium` but it looks like it only works in a remote browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RSelenium` will be exactly what you are looking for. The package can drive; `Firefox`, `Chrome` & `phatonJS` off the top of my head.

Installation depends on the browser you wish to use and also the OS you are running on. Assuming you want to use the default `Firefox`, and have it installed, it will be as simple as:

```
# RSelenium::startServer() if required
require(RSelenium)
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost" 
                      , port = 4444
                      , browserName = "firefox"
                      )
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://www.url.com")
```

Once you have got to there you can move and interact with DOM elements using `ID`, `XPath`, `css`, `class`, etc.

Full documentation on how to interact and input values to DOM elements can be found at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html

Using `chrome` and `phantomjs` is fairly simple on OSX using homebrew. `Chrome` is slightly more awkward on windows as you will need to manually add the path to the `chromedriver` to system `PATH` variable.